# Need to Access Multiple Image Textures from a Single Bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine

What i need is to access multiple images from inside of a  single asset bundle.

```
        IEnumerator LoadTexture(WWW www, string textureName){

    textureBundle = www.assetBundle;

    if(textureBundle != null)
    {  
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textureName))
        {
            textureObject = textureBundle.mainAsset as Texture2D;

        }
        else
        {
            textureObject = textureBundle.Load(textureName, typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;

        }
    }
    else
    {   

        Debug.LogError("No asset bundle can be found for given URL.");
        yield break;
    }

    if(textureObject == null)
    {

        Debug.LogWarning("Memory Saved");
        yield break;
    }

    //textureBundle.Unload(true); 

}
```

this is the code i am using. Just changing the name and trying to access the other data in the assetbundle isnt working. Any Suggestion?

Comment: Your tags should not be in your title. Please tell us *how* your code isn't working -- does it throw an error? Does it not load any textues? Does it only load the one? Check other things with your program -- are you sure that you're using the correct directory structure for your program?

Comment: Sry about that!  what i am doing is changing the texture dynamically by loading it from the bundle itself and at the time of changing the scene am unloading it, so that i can reuse it. Problem is it only loads one texture , that is the main texture "textureBundle.mainAsset as Texture2D" and afterwards i am not able to traverse inside the bundle, when i try to look for other images/texture. Rest of the code is working perfectly, Just this one thing is making it fall apart

Comment: I have multiple AssetBundles and i am able to access one image per bundle, but that is ruining the whole concept of "Asset Bundle", all should be in one file. Need Help with this part.

Comment: I guess i have Figured Out the reason Behind it - u can only access the Bundle once in the scene and store it in an array or something and use the asset from there. Thanks Anyways